# if statement with two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

```
display (df)
display(prices)
```

[I have 2 dataframes, I want to replace the month numbers in dataframe 1 with the DA HB West value for that month. It also has to have the same cheat code as the df.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAjEW.png)

I feel like this is really easy to do but I keep getting an error.

The error reads "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

Comment: Kindly provide data as text, not pics

Answer (score 0):

With a sample of your data:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Month": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
                    "DA HB West": np.random.random(12),
                    "Year": [2019]*12,
                    "Cheat": ["2019PeakWE"]*12})

df = pd.DataFrame({"Month1": [7, 7, 7, 9, 11],
                   "Month2": [8, 8, 8, 10, 12],
                   "Month3": [9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 11.0, np.nan],
                   "Cheat4": ["2019PeakWE"]*5})
df.columns = df.columns.str[:-1]
```

Fill the na values so that there isn't an error with changing value types to integers:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Map all but the last column:

```
d = {}
for i, j in df.groupby("Cheat"):
    mapping = df2[df2["Cheat"] == i].set_index("Month")["DA HB West"].to_dict()
    d[i]  = j
    d[i].iloc[:, :-1] = j.iloc[:, :-1].astype(int).apply(lambda x: x.map(mapping))
```

This creates a dictionary of all the different Cheats.

You can then append them all together, if you need to.